# Moving Data Between PySpark, SparkR, and Scala Interpreters

Tags: pyspark, sparkr, apache-zeppelin

Using Apache Zeppelin, I have the following notebook paragraphs that load content into the zeppelinContext object.  One from python (pyspark):

```
%pyspark
py_list = [5,6,7,8]
z.put("p1", py_list)
```

And one from scala (spark):

```
val scala_arr1 = Array(Array(1, 4), Array(8, 16))
z.put("s1", scala_arr1)

val scala_arr2 = Array(1,2,3,4)
z.put("s2", scala_arr2)

val scala_vec = Vector(4,3,2,1)
z.put("s3", scala_vec)
```

I am trying to access these values from a sparkR paragraph using the following:

```
%r
unlist(z.get("s1"))
unlist(z.get("s2"))
unlist(z.get("s3"))
unlist(z.get("p1"))
```

However, the result is:

```
[1]  1  4  8 16
[1] 1 2 3 4
Java ref type scala.collection.immutable.Vector id 51 
Java ref type java.util.ArrayList id 53
```

**How can I get the values that were in the scala Vector and the python list?**  Have scala and java objects inside an R interpretter is not particularly useful because to my knowledge no R functions can make sense of them.  Am I outside the range of what zeppelin is currently capable of?  I am on a snapshot of zeppelin-0.6.0.

Comment: Did you find any answer for your questions? Have you ask Zeppelin to clarify your issues? I'm curious!

Comment: @MTT no answers yet.. my current work around is to write to a temp table.  Hopefully we can find something less ackward soon